# переопределение метода qcombobox setText

Tags: c++, qt

Переопределил стандартный *view* у *QComboBox* по [этому](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57911-QComboBox-drop-down-list-as-table#post_258454) примеру:

```
// создаем и настраиваем модель
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
model->setItem(0, 0, new QStandardItem("111"));
model->setItem(0, 1, new QStandardItem("Name 1"));
model->setItem(1, 0, new QStandardItem("222"));
model->setItem(1, 1, new QStandardItem("Name 2"));

// создаем и настраиваем view
QTableView *coilView = new QTableView(this);
coilView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
coilView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
coilView->verticalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
coilView->verticalHeader()->hide();
coilView->horizontalHeader()->hide();
coilView->setColumnWidth(0, 50);

ui->comboBox->setView(coilView);
ui->comboBox->setModel(model); 

// присоединяю слот для обработки textChanged
connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(textChanged(int)));
```

В результате в выпадающем списке получаю следующее:
[image: combobox sample]

По умолчанию значение в комбобоксе устанавливается по первому столбцу (т.е. по коду). А мне нужно сделать так, чтоб в свёрнутом комбобоксе отображалось имя, а не код.

Я пробовал сделать через сигнал `currentIndexChanged(int index)`:

```
void MainWindow::textChanged(int index)
{
    QStandardItemModel *model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(ui->comboBox->model());
    QString name = model->item(index, 1)->text();
    QLineEdit *line = ui->comboBox->lineEdit();

    qDebug() << name;    // ОК! в выводе приложения вижу корректное имя
    line->setText(name); // и тут программа падает....
}
```

Как правильно изменить строку, которая записывается в LineEdit?

Comment: Судя по всему комбобокс нередактируемый, а это значит, что `ui->comboBox->lineEdit();` возвращает `0` и дальше крэшится при попытке вызвать `setText` для нулевого объекта.

Comment: @älёxölüt, так оно и есть... но делать редактируемым, как по мне, не совсем целесообразно (ведь коды и названия приходят из БД)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ui->comboBox->setModelColumn(1);
```

см. [QComboBox::modelColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#modelColumn-prop)